# How to set a default value to datetime_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to set a default value for datetime_field inside the view. I have checked multiple sources and all fail to give the correct results.

For instance this example does not work
https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

```
datetime_field("user", "born_on", min: "2014-05-20T00:00:00")
# => <input id="user_born_on" name="user[born_on]" type="datetime-local" min="2014-05-20T00:00:00.000" />
```

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <%= f.datetime_field(:date_reported, class: "form-control col-sm-3", min: "2014-05-20T00:00:00") %>
</div>
```

My code displays this:

[image]

Comment: try passing a ```value``` key :    ```<%= f.datetime_field(:date_reported, class: "form-control col-sm-3", min: "2014-05-20T00:00:00", value: "2014-05-20T00:00:00" ) %>```

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked :)

Answer (score 3):

Answer to my question:

## Inside controller

```
def new
  @mine = Mine.new
  @time_now = Time.new.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%k:%M")
end
```

## Inside View

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.datetime_field(:date_reported, class: "form-control col-sm-3", value: @time_now ) %>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%k:%M")` you'll want to use `.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")` to make sure the hours are zero-padded instead of blank-padded (which won't work for single digit hours)

Comment: The comment above was the clarifying thing that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

The object linked to your form object (`f`), needs to have its attribute set to the default value you want to input.

If you do something like this, it should work

```
<% f.object.date_reported = Date.new(1984, 1, 12) %>
<div class="form-group">
   <%= f.datetime_field(:date_reported, class: "form-control col-sm-3", min: "2014-05-20T00:00:00") %>
</div>
```

Please note that normally, setting a default value on your form should be done in the related controller, rather than in the view.

Comment: Thanks, I'll attempt this tomorrow and let you know